# How to make 4 divs float left and one float right with this order?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this 5 divs float left and right with this order:

1 4

2 4

3 4

5 4

Only if the screen width is more than 600px and less than 1024px.
The div 4 has the height of all other divs together, and if the screen width is less than 600px I want to display them one below each other like this:

1

2

3

4

5

Here's my example code:

```
<div class=group>
  <div class="block one">Block One Left</div>
  <div class="block two">Block Two Left</div>
  <div class="block three">Block Three Left</div>
  <div class="block four">Block Four right</div>
  <div class="block five">Block Five Left</div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.group {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.one, .two, .three, .five {
  height: 30px;
}
.four {
  height: 160px;
}
```

And a codepen to illustrate the situation:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NberNM

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Depending on the rest of your structure, you can make .four positioned absolute with right:0 ; After resolution change, you can remove absolute position.
Block elements can have display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the element widths are, you could always position it absolute (make sure to relative position the container).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWoLgx

To only do it if the device width is less than 600px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .four {
      height: 160px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 220px;
      top: -5px;
    }
}
```

Note, I've also used flex on the blocks to align them how they are but this could be done using display block.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNoKLK

Comment: As @armin posted, you could use right: 0; rather than left.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will work. In the first codepen, the four div is not align with the first, instead its aligned with the five. Its that correct?

Comment: You can also add top: 0; if you want it to be aligned at the top of relative container

Comment: For me it is aligned at the top? I have added "top: 0;" to ensure thats the case for you too. 

Note, the 2nd code pen has the media query on it to only style that way for max width of 600px;

Comment: Also, how I can center the two collums independent of the width of the screen? margin: 0 auto will not work because of the absolute positioning right?

Comment: Have  you tried? It looks to still be in the centre. If your code is up somewhere I can take a look. If your original question has been answered please accept.

Comment: Yeah, the collumn is aligned to the left and not centered. Look at this pen please: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbZjey I changed the  (max-width: 600px) to (mix-width: 600px) so it will only display two collumn on larger screen. and in smaller just one. But the content is not centered yet.

Comment: .group is aligned centrally, but because its width is way bigger than its content it looks offest. Set its width to 425 instead of 700 and it is central?

Comment: Any way to make it centered with an auto width? Also, I wil accept the answer too. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, add a container and align that, though this is only if you know the widths of its contents. I've used padding-right to the value of the absolutely positioned "div four" width

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQvLxB

Answer (score 0):

This might be help. I have used position for fourth div on medium screen.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .group > * {
    display: block;
    background: red;
  }
  .four {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .group > * {
    display: block;
  }
   .four {
    float: initial;
    position: initial;
    left: initial;
    top: initial;
  }
}
```